# Abort ajax request without affecting the next request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a number input and "onChange" event, where I'm triggering this ajax request (see the code).
This aborting affects my next request. 
If I'm sending only one request without aborting , the request has a normal speed but if I'm aborting, like 3 requests, the ajax looks like it's sending, in one request, all the aborted requests...

```js
 globalAjaxChange = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: ajaxUrl,
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    beforeSend: function () {
        if (globalAjaxChange != null) {
            globalAjaxChange.abort();
        }
    },
    success: function (data) {
        if (data['ok'] == false) {
            notify(data['msg'], 'error');
        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
        if (data.statusText !== 'abort')
            notify('message', 'error');
    }
});
```

Here is the network inspection:

[image: Network Inspection]

Comment: Can you share what the load is on the "bloated" request?

Comment: Is your code in global scope or is it defined inside a function?

Comment: The code is in a function but the globalAjaxChange is declared global.

Answer (score 1):

Try returning try/false in your `beforeSend` callback. Unless you need to send the ajax request anyway, jQuery will abort the request for you with a return of `false` in that function. See the [jQuery docs here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more info on the callback methods.

You also might be having a logic or async issue on the set of the `globalAjaxChange` variable. Which would cause the ajax request to always send by never returning null on your check for `globalAjaxChange`. Try placing breakpoints around where it sends and gets set at, to see what the values are.